# Why can't I run Vim 8.2 from the LXDE menu?

Tags: vim, desktop, lxde

I uninstalled Vim 8.0 with `sudo apt remove vim-common`, and compiled and installed the latest version:

```
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd  vim/src
make
sudo make install
```

I can run Vim 8.2 with `vim` in a terminal.

This is the `.desktop` file for Vim 8.2:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Vim
Comment=text editor
Exec=/home/debian/vim/src/vim  %F
Icon=/home/debian/vim/src/vim.ico
Type=Application
MimeType=text/plain
Categories=GTK;Utility;TextEditor;
Keywords=text;editor;vim;
```

Why can't I run Vim from the menu? When I click on "Vim" in the menu, Vim doesn't pop up.

[image]

It makes no difference if I use:

```
Exec=/home/debian/vim/src/vim  %F
```

or

```
Exec=/usr/local/bin/vim  %F
```

I am using `lxterminal` in `debian`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your terminal, type `which vim` and check you're using the correct path.

`vim` is a text-based program and needs to be run in a terminal. In order for your `.desktop` file to work, you'd need to add the line: `Terminal=true`, like so:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Vim
Comment=text editor
Exec=/home/debian/vim/src/vim  %F
Icon=/home/debian/vim/src/vim.ico
Type=Application
MimeType=text/plain
Categories=GTK;Utility;TextEditor;
Keywords=text;editor;vim;
Terminal=true
```

There is a GUI version of Vim available, usually invoked with `gvim` from the command line. If you compiled Vim with graphical support, you may want to use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run that command in a terminal window.

`vim` is a commandline program which will not open a graphical user interface. When clicking the icon perhaps the program is run but you cannot see it.

In the launcher's `Properties` go into `Edit` (where you can change the path), then check the box `Run in Terminal`.

Answer (score 0):

What terminal emulator do you use? Call it through this. An example for `xfce4-terminal`:

`vim.desktop`

```
Exec=xfce4-terminal -T ViM -I gvim --hide-scrollbar -e "vim %F"
```

Whatever terminal you use, `-e` is used to execute a command inside the terminal.

Comment: I am using `lxterminal` in `debian`.

Comment: Try `Exec=lxterminal -t ViM -e "vim %F"` or `Exec=lxterminal -t ViM -e vim %F`. `-t` is just for the title of the window. Probably you also need to insert the full path for vim, for example `/usr/local/bin/vim`, since you compiled it yourself.